# Hive external table pointing to CSV file with embedded double quotes

Tags: csv, hadoop, hive, hiveql

I am trying to create an external Hive table pointing to a CSV file.
My CSV file has a column(col2) that could have double quotes and comma as part of the column value.

Data in each column:

```
Col1 : 150
Col2 : BATWING, ABC "D " TEST DATA
Col3 : 300
```

Row in CSV:

```
150,"BATWING, ABC ""D "" TEST DATA",300
```

Create table DDL :

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE test (
   col1 INT, 
   col2 STRING, 
   col3 INT) 
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ESCAPED BY '"' 
LOCATION 's3://test-folder/test-file.csv'
```

When I query the table, I see null values in col3.

What am I missing here while creating the table? Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Use `OpenCSVSerde`. Here is an example

Create table

```
CREATE TABLE bala (col1 int, col2 string, col3 int)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES(
  "separatorChar" = ",", "escapeChar"='\"'
);
```

Load data

```
hive>LOAD DATA INPATH '/../test.csv' INTO TABLE bala
Loading data to table bala
Table testing.bala stats: [numFiles=1, totalSize=40]
OK
Time taken: 0.514 seconds
```

Check if it has loaded

```
hive> select * from bala;
OK
150 BATWING, ABC "D " TEST DATA 300
Time taken: 0.288 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
```

Comment: :-
I am having double quotes in my Text - Column sample - "5f367c99e4b0799af79a2b89","The Washingtons: George and Martha, "Join'd by Friendship, Crown'd by Love"","" In here second column has couple of double quotes inside. I tried the same thing as above, but it did not help me out. Still the issue was there . Anything can be done to fix on that ?

Answer (score 0):

```html
Create hive external table:

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ${hiveconf:dbnm}.tblnm ;
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE ${hiveconf:dbnm}.tblnm (
C1 string,
C2 string
)
PARTITIONED BY (C3 string)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde' 
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
    "separatorChar" = '|'  (change it to your separator)
   ,"quoteChar"     = '\"'
) 
STORED AS TEXTFILE 
LOCATION '/hdfspath' 
--tblproperties ("skip.header.line.count"="1")
;
MSCK REPAIR TABLE ${hiveconf:dbnm}.tblnm;
```